# Can I change webrtc stream source for Android webview?

Tags: android, webview, webrtc

I want to change media stream source from capturing video from camera to another source such as video file, while I using webview. Can I do it ?

Comment: I believe you can. I haven't tested it myself but you have to create your own video renderer by extending `BaseVideoRenderer` class. I did some modification to incoming frames using ffmpeg lib and extending `BaseVideoRenderer` class